# PSQL updating ENUM fails

Tags: sql, postgresql

## Description

There is a complex project details of which are out of scope of this ticket. There is a initial SQL file. There is a migration.

### Problem

Migration fails.

### The model

```
CREATE TYPE plugin_status AS ENUM (
  'uninstalled',
  'installing',
  'installed',
  'uninstalling',
  'error'
);

...

CREATE TABLE test_agent_plugin_status (
  id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () PRIMARY KEY,
  status plugin_status DEFAULT 'uninstalled',
);
```

### Migration

#### Variant 1

```
-- +migrate Up

BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE test_agent_plugin_status
    ALTER status TYPE text;

CREATE TYPE plugin_status_new AS ENUM (
    'uninstalled',
    'installing',
    'installed',
    'uninstalling'
);

ALTER TABLE test_agent_plugin_status
    ALTER status TYPE plugin_status_new
    USING status::plugin_status_new;

DROP TYPE plugin_status;

ALTER TYPE plugin_status_new RENAME TO plugin_status;

COMMIT;
```

#### Variant 2

```
-- +migrate Up

ALTER TABLE test_agent_plugin_status
    ALTER status TYPE text;

DROP TYPE plugin_status;

CREATE TYPE plugin_status AS ENUM (
    'uninstalled',
    'installing',
    'installed',
    'uninstalling'
);

ALTER TABLE test_agent_plugin_status
    ALTER status TYPE plugin_status
    USING test_agent_plugin_status::plugin_status;

-- +migrate Down
```

The error message says.

[image]

Banging the head against the wall for couple of hours now. The project is complex. Powered by Kubernetes and Go.

Does the PostgreSQL commands look correct? It seems like whenever the migration is ran it is never executed as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `DEFAULT` clause of the enum column is the problem

```
ALTER TABLE test_agent_plugin_status
    ALTER status TYPE plugin_status_new
    USING status::plugin_status_new;

-- SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: default for column "status" cannot be cast automatically to type plugin_status_new
```

A possible workaround is to drop the `DEFAULT` clause and create is again with the new enum type

```
alter table test_agent_plugin_status 
ALTER column status drop default;

ALTER TABLE test_agent_plugin_status
    ALTER status TYPE plugin_status_new
    USING status::plugin_status_new;

alter table test_agent_plugin_status 
ALTER column status set default  'uninstalled'::plugin_status_new;
```